# Dual citizenship, USA & Ecuador. USA Passport expired, plane leaves in 9 hours

Tags: passports, ecuador

Girlfriend (born in Ecuador) leaving for Ecuador in 9 hours, she JUST realized her USA passport is expired. She can get a USA passport tomorrow at the fed building but will miss her flight.

Does anyone know for certain if she can just use her Ecuador passport both ways?

I cant find a straight answer anywhere online except a similar UK/US passport and "no" answers from places that charge $500 for 24 hour passports. Similar StackExchange answers are "maybe/yes"

Comment: If I were in her shoes I'd fly to Ecuador and then try to get a US passport from the embassy before returning. She certainly cannot return with the Ecuador passport because it does not contain a valid US visa and the airline will not let her board the plane. How long is she planning to stay there?

Comment: July 27th. She is concerned about how "things are done" in Ecuador. It takes all day to get anything done, if ANYTHING is wrong, any typo, etc, they wont help her. often a $5 - $10 bribe involved and she is worried she may be missing something to renew when she gets down there. I told her it would be via the embassy and not a corrupt place like the Ecuadorean "DMV", but she is still worried. I think a $300 plane change fee and getting the USA passport may be best. Thank you!

Comment: The US embassy will not play those games.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: US consulates abroad ABSOLUTELY play those games and the levels of incompetency or sheer abuse that we've experienced has been  astonishing.

Answer (score 5):

I would say she's worrying for nothing in regard to the efficiency of the US embassy, it's staffed by Americans not Ecuadorian(I like your DMV analogy). She should enter Ecuador as planned with her Ecuadorian passport and apply for her new US passport at the Embassy in Ecuador. According to the embassy's website, passports take 10-15 days to be issued. Further info can be found here: https://ec.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/passports/

Comment: thank you. She is still leery of trying to rely on the delivery as well. It is also in Quito, not near where she will be. She did a $300 ticket change and will renew it downtown in the morning. Oh, and I did mean the DMV in Ecuador, I just didnt know what it is called. Took us 3 trips (days) and 4-6 hours a day to fill out the paperwork correctly. And a $20 bill (sorry off-topic). She is scared to try anything in Ecuador, even when I said it is staffed by Americans and not "in" Ecuador.

Answer (score 5):

Update and thanks:

They moved the passport office to another building but she managed to get there at 10AM. Had the passport in hand at 2PM. Changed flight for $300 fee for Saturday. No problems.

THANK YOU ALL

Comment: How much was the passport fee?